# how to replace [ symbol from string?

Tags: java, android

Have this symbol from my list which coming from server Begin: [[ End: ]]

This is must be just one not two. How I can remove other one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the String `.replace` method.
You should be able to do something like this:

`yourString.replace("[[", "[");`

If this is not enough to you, please give me more details about your problem.

Comment: I'm saving ArrayList in SQLite. When I fech the data, it's coming what I said. I tired this replace maybe 10 time but still same.

Comment: Did you try to save the returned value like: `yourString = yourString.replace("[[","[");` ?

Comment: @Nina how did you solve this issue by just using `yourString.replace("[[", "[");` It will just replace opening brackets [[ to [ but what about closing brackets ]] ?

Comment: You can do the same with the closing brackets. It should be something like this:
 `yourString = yourString.replace("[[","[").replace("]]","]");`. Happy to hear that it works.

Comment: Yeah, but for this simple case calling **replace** method twice doesn't look good.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = "Begin: [[ End: ]]";

// will replace two square brackets with one
s = s.replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]");
```

with regular expression

```
String s = "Begin: [[ End: ]]";

// will replace two or more square brackets with one
s = s.replaceAll("\\[\\[+", "[").replaceAll("\\]\\]+", "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove first and last character

```
String message = "[[message]]";
message = message.substring(1, message.length()-1);
```